# partial fraction of $\prod_{i=1}^{n}1/(\lambda_{i}+x)$ and its integration

Tags: calculus

For positive scalars $\lambda_{i}$, the partial fraction of $\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\lambda_{i}+x}$ can be obtained easily for $n=2,3$. Then the integration $\int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\lambda_{i}+x}dx$  can be computed correspondingly for $n=2,3$.

The question is that what is the partial fraction and its integration for larger $n$?

PS: The integration correponds to the first and second divided difference of the logarithm function $f(x) =\ln(x)$ for $n=2,3$, respectively. So it is natural to think the correpondence may be correct for larger $n$.

Answer (score 3):

The partial fraction decomposition is
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\lambda_i+x} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\alpha_i}{\lambda_i+x}, \qquad \alpha_i=\prod_{j\neq i}\frac{1}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i}
\end{equation}
because $g_i(x) = (\lambda_i+x)f(x)$ satisfies $g_i(-\lambda_i) = \alpha_i$.

Answer (score 3):

The partial fractions of $\prod_{i=1}^n 1/(x+\lambda_i)$ can be easily calculated by writing this as

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{A_i}{x+\lambda_i} $$

and solving it to get

$$A_i = -\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{n} \frac{1}{\lambda_i - \lambda_j}$$

since the function $\phi_i(x)$ defined by$$\phi_i(x) = (x+\lambda_i)\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x+\lambda_k}$$ satisfies the equation $\phi_i(-\lambda_i) = A_i$.